# If two random variables follow the same distribution, does it mean X=Y?

Tags: probability

The question here is:

Find the covariance of $X$ and $Y^{2}$ when
$X $~ $N(0,1)$
$Y $~ $N(0,1)$

Do $Cov(X, Y^{2})$ and $Cov(X, X^{2})$ have the same value?
Or, is $Cov(X, Y^{2})$ equal to $Cov(X, X^{2})$ ?

Comment: For the question of the title the short answer is: no. And the long answer: no, no. You can define an uniform distribution in $[0,1]$ and a different one in $[1,2]$, both function who domain is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: This distinction is the entire point of "**independent** and **identically distributed**".

Comment: You cannot calculate $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y^2)$ without information regarding joint distribution of $(X,Y)$. But $\operatorname{Cov}(X,X^2)$ can be directly calculated of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This distinction is the entire point of "**independent** and **identically distributed**" random variables.

In fact this question is completely underdefined. Without restriction, the relationship between $X$ and $Y$ can be anything, from (as an unstated assumption, actually) the same, to independent, to completely anticorrelated ($X=-Y$).

Comment: So my guess was wrong. I'll try other ways.