# Covariance of $X$ and $Y^2$, when $X,Y$ follow $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability

The question is as follows:

**Find $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y^{2})$ when

$X\sim N(0,1)$

$Y\sim N(0,1)$

$\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)=p$ (where $-1<p<1$)**

---

I got to:
$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,  Y^{2})=E[(X-0)(Y^{2}-1)] = E[XY^{2}-X] = E[XY^{2}]$$
But I have no idea what to do from here. Cov$(X, Y)=E[XY]=p$ so what??

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ jointly normal?

Comment: Assuming X and Y are jointly normal, I'm getting that the answer is independent of p...perhaps I made an error?

Comment: As was pointed out in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3704786/321264), you need the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ to answer the question. So the question as stated is incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

First of all let's detail all the information we have:

Due to the fact that we know the two marginals distribution and their covariance, as we are in a Gaussian model, we know all of our model:

$X,Y$ are joint Gaussian so the joint distribution can be factorized in

$f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_{Y|X}(y|x)$

$f(x)$ is standard gaussian while

$f(y|x) \sim N(\rho x;(1-\rho^2))$

Now let's attack

$\mathbb{E}(XY^2)=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(XY^2|X))=\mathbb{E}(x\mathbb{E}(Y^2|X))$

Now observe that

$\mathbb{E}(Y^2|X)=\mathbb{V}(Y|X)+\mathbb{E}^2(Y|X)=1-\rho^2+\rho^2x^2$

concluding we have

$Cov(X,Y^2)=\mathbb{E}(XY^2)=\mathbb{E}(X(1-\rho^2)+X^3\rho^2)=0$

as all odd moments of the standard gaussian are zero

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume joint normality.

Here's a hint: You can show that $E[X|Y]=pY$. The law of iterated expectations then gives you the result: $0$.

Intuitively, this makes sense due to symmetry: if I tell you that $Y^2$ is large, you know that $|Y|$ must be large, but that tells you that $Y$ or $-Y$ is large, which means that we expect $X$ or $-X$ to be large, but not which one of the two is large. That is, we don't actually know whether $X$ is large or small.