# Covariance of $X$ and $Y^2$ where $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, covariance, bivariate-distributions

I'm trying to solve a case where there is bivariate random vector $(X,Y)$ that has the bivariate normal distribution below ($-1<\rho<1$):

> $$\begin{pmatrix}
>   X\\ 
>   Y
> \end{pmatrix}\sim N_{2}\left(\begin{pmatrix}
>   0\\ 
>   0
> \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
>   1 & \rho\\ 
>   \rho & 1
> \end{pmatrix}\right)$$

I am trying to get covariance of $X$ and $Y^2$ but not sure how to do this. I remember that taking square of normal distribution gives chi-square distribution, but in the case of bivariate case, I am not sure how to get covariance of $X$ and $Y^2$. Could someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: So the expected value of X is X? This doesn´t seem right to me.

Comment: @callculus oh sorry, they should be all 0, my mistake. just fixed it

Comment: Recently asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3705032/321264.

Comment: Consider that
$$\mathbb E(X Y^2) = \mathbb E((-X) (-Y)^2)$$
because $(X, Y) \overset d = (-X, -Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: I will assume that $EX=EY=0$ for simplicity but the general case is not harder.  If $a=\frac {EXY} {EX^{2}}$ the $X$ and $Y-aX$ are jointly normal with covariance $0$. Hence they are independent. Now $$EXY^{2}=EX((Y-aX)+aX)^{2}$$ $$=EX(Y-aX)^{2}+a
^{2} EX^{3}+2aEX^{2}(Y-aX)$$ $$=EXE(Y-aX)^{2}+a
^{2} EX^{3}+2aEX^{2}E(Y-aX)$$ which can be computed easily.